# Upgrade XNA 4.0 solution to MonoGame

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, xna, upgrade, monogame

Could someone explain, how to "transform" an existing XNA 4.0 solution to a MonoGame Windows Phone 8?
My XNA solution has 4 projects:
1. contains the Game() class
2. Content which includes the .fbx model (rigged 3D hand)
3. the Model proj with 4 classes (AnimationClip, AnimationPlayer, Keyframe, SkinningData)
4. Pipeline, where the ContentProcessor() is

Nothing special in the code, it was written on the basis of "Better skinned sample". In the Game() class I wrote a method, which provide a skeletal animation. It works perfectly, but I have to upgrade to MonoGame, because of some integration issues.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I recently did exactly what you asked for my own game.

You can start as you are. Almost 100% of the source code that worked in an XNA 4.0 project is compatible with MonoGame. Essentially copy over the code to the new project and you are good to go.

The only issue is with the content loading. I highly suggest you use the nugget packages to install Monogame on a solution and create a content project. From my experience fbx models are supported OK at the moment and can be compiled to xnb just OK.

Comment: So roughly, I create a new MonoGame WP8 project, add the XNA projects and replace the Game class, am I right? (I have the xnb files too)

Comment: You create a new MonoGame WP8 project and copy the files from your XNA project into the MonoGame project. If you have the xnb files you can use them as they are as they are already compiled.

Comment: Content creation is something of an issue, so if you do not need the content project, do not create it. I had several big issues with Visual Studio 2013 Update 2, where it killed my code editor (it never appeared), which were fixed in Update 3. In the past you HAD to use the XNA content project.

Comment: Add the xnb files to the Content folder, add the AnimationPlayer, AnimationClip, Keyframe, SkinningData and the Game1 classes to the Mono project and it's almost done, right? Thank you for your help!